# Searching a dictionary in a list through a flask API

Tags: python, list, dictionary, flask, postman

Am trying to search a `dictionary` inside a `list`, via a `URL` while using **POST** method, am doing this using **postman**. The `URL` example which searches is as below:

http://localhost:5000/api/v1/7/requests

where there's **7** is an id  , this is posted and is searched in the list of dictionary if it exists. This is the sample list of a `dictionary` I want to search.

```
[
        {
            "id": 1,
            "offer_details": "This offer cuts down 3% of the drive, you want ",
            "offer_name": "eid offer ",
            "offer_price": 8000
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "offer_details": "This offer cuts down 3% of the drive, you want ",
            "offer_name": "supper offer ",
            "offer_price": 8000
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "offer_details": "This offer cuts down 3% of the drive, you want ",
            "offer_name": "easter offer ",
            "offer_price": 8000
        }
    ]
```

***So below is my code , I want to adjust it to search well the list if the id is available or not.***

*Currently the code is not searching well the list*

```
class RequestRideOffer(Resource):

    def post(self, rideId):

        parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        parser.add_argument('token', location='headers')      
        args = parser.parse_args()

        if not args['token']:
            return make_response(jsonify({"message": "Token is missing"}), 401)
        decoded = decode_token(args['token'])
        if decoded["status"] == "Failure":
            return make_response(jsonify({"message": decoded["message"]}), 401)
        if decoded['isDriver'] == "False":
            return make_response(jsonify({"message": "Invalid for Drivers "}), 401)

                # return make_response(jsonify({"message": "Meal not found"}), 404)
                #performing a search for the rideId
        if not any(d['id'] == rideId for d in rides_list):
            return make_response(jsonify({"message": "Request has been made successfully."}), 400)
        else :
            return make_response(jsonify({"message": "Sorry,No ride offer available for your request."}), 400)


        return make_response(jsonify({"message": "Invalid request, please insert again."}), 400)
```

This how I was searching in the code above ,how can I improve this code:

```
#performing a search for the rideId
    if not any(d['id'] == rideId for d in rides_list):
        return make_response(jsonify({"message": "Request has been made successfully."}), 400)
    else :
        return make_response(jsonify({"message": "Sorry,No ride offer available for your request."}), 400)
```

Comment: can you limit your code example to the part relevant to your question? what is the test (code line with `assert`) for the behavoir you want?

Comment: @EvgenyPogrebnyak, I have edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you simply can use `in`:

```
if rideId in [x['id'] for x in rides_list]:
   ...
```

Some example:

```
rideId = 2
rides_list = [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "offer_details": "This offer cuts down 3% of the drive, you want ",
            "offer_name": "eid offer ",
            "offer_price": 8000
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "offer_details": "This offer cuts down 3% of the drive, you want ",
            "offer_name": "supper offer ",
            "offer_price": 8000
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "offer_details": "This offer cuts down 3% of the drive, you want ",
            "offer_name": "easter offer ",
            "offer_price": 8000
        }
    ]

if rideId in [x['id'] for x in rides_list]:
    print('Found it!', rideId)
```

Comment: Glad it worked for you! also have a second look at your status codes - I think you need something other than `400` in 'No ride offer available for your request' and 'Invalid request, please insert again.'

Comment: `"message": "Request has been made successfully."}), 200` - this is success, right?, `jsonify({"message": "Sorry, no ride offer available for your request."}), 200` this is success too - the api worked, and `make_response(jsonify({"message": "Invalid request, please insert again."}), 400)` is really a malformed request error, its 400.